# Performing backward variable selection in R based on test data prediction

Tags: r, model, data-modeling, cross-validation

How can I apply backwards variable selection based on performance on test data in R?

I already know that there is the stepAIC() function which does almost what i want, but in every step it removes one variable based on the AIC criteria. i want to do the same with test and training data and remove the variable in every step based on prediction performance.

Comment: you're probably going to have to write this yourself ...

Comment: Really? But how is it possible, I'm the first one that wants to do that? is there sth wrong about this approach?

Comment: I can't say for sure that it *doesn't* exist. In general AIC is a pretty good approximation of out-of-sample performance (asymptotically, AIC is equivalent to leave-one-out cross-validation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322537/if-the-aic-and-the-bic-are-asymptotically-equivalent-to-cross-validation-is-it )

Comment: So (continuing) I think people don't generally bother.  Either they would filter on AIC or adjusted R^2 or something, *or* they would use something like LASSO to select (wrappers vs embedded methods, e.g. see https://sebastianraschka.com/faq/docs/feature_sele_categories.html )